# Merging Amazon EBS volumes

Tags: amazon-web-services, merge, volume

I have an Amazon EBS volume that is 100% full. Therefore, I created a new volume and expected it to work but it didn't.

[image]

How can I merge the volume I created with the current one?

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this from AWS. It is **OS-level operation** which you have to do yourself. And you do this as you would on your local operating system, which requires repatriationing your hard drives and, for example, setting up a filesystem, e.g. using [LVM](https://linoxide.com/lvm-configuration-linux/).

In your case it could be just easier to [extend your existing volume](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/recognize-expanded-volume-linux.html), rather then create and "marge" new one.

Comment: ahan ok............... so I can increase the volume from the dashboard of aws also, right?